# Yii grid-view bugs: sorting after filtering

Tags: php, apache, iis, gridview, yii

I am newable on Yii and I found the following bugs on the Yii default grid-view, may I ask if there are any solutions to fix the bugs? Thanks!!

1. I have a normal grid-view in the Yii application when a number of fields and dropdown filter

[image: http://holland.pk/uptow/i4/9ff7a962b0c29a2c15c6d0e1c7572a8c.png]

2. Then I tried to filter records by the dropdown box and sort the records afterwards, the following problems were occurred!

[image: http://holland.pk/uptow/i4/18dd6616c0fcbbe0573d3a93a4e09fc0.png]

The name of the drodown filter (membership no, address and status) were shown on the textbox filter automatically.

The related code is as follows:

View:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'member-address-district-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'filter' => $model,
    'columns' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'region_id',
            'filter' => CHtml::listData(MemberAddressRegion::model()->findAll(),'id','item_name'),
            'value' => '$data->region->item_name',
            ),
        'item_name',
        array(
            'name' => 'status',
            'filter' => helper::statusArray(),
            'value' => array($model, 'renderGridDataStatus')),
        'item_order',
        /*
         */
        array(
            'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
));
```

I found this problem would be occurred in IIS server only, but not the Apache, so how to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I made a small list of things to check when making sure a Yii app worked on IE too. I've saved it here: [Making Yii apps work on IE too.](http://queirozf.com/reminders/stuff-you-need-to-know-to-make-yii-web-apps-work-on-ie-too). Sorry for self-advertising like that but I think it's the quickest way to help you.

Since you're using UTF-8 languages, make sure that your HTML and you PHP are set to work with UTF-8. Some browsers may detect that automatically but maybe IE doesn't.